# Word equivalent to "prestation" in French in the administrative field

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, translation, french

I'm searching for an English word which could have the same meaning than the word "prestation" in french, in the sense of "*some service (paid or not) that has been executed by an administrative entity.*"

For example, as a citizen, you may request a specific document or initiate procedure such as a planning permission that requires the authorities to carry out a certain amount of work, such as searching for documents or going through administrative departments to check that your request complies with local legislation or regulations, etc.

The word "prestation" in french can be seen in such sentences:

> Le présent règlement régit les tarifs requis pour les **prestations** du Département de la communication et des affaires extérieures.

> Règles relatives à la description des **prestations** de l'administration fédérale.

The most common occurrence I have found in English is "service" but it seems too vague or too general for me.

Comment: If you pluralize it - services- , it points to something(s) more specific.

Comment: The word in English for this is **services**. The French can't use that here **les services** here for obvious reasons. I do French-to-English translations and can guarantee this is the standard translation of the term.

Comment: Providing an English-language sentence and context would be useful.

Comment: "*Service provision*" matches with the first french example and just "*services*" for the second.

Comment: These regulations govern the rates for the services of the Communication and Foreign Affairs Department (or Ministry).  This is Switzerland. It has a federal system unlike France and Belgium, for example. These départements are in fact what are called ministries in other European countries but departments in the US.

Comment: Rules for describing the services of the federal administration. //The federal administration supports the government (the Federal Council) so it can carry out its tasks. The federal administration drafts laws  and legal measures. https://www.easyvote.ch/fr/Savoir/lexique/easyvote-lexicon-bundesverwaltung

Answer (score 2):

***Service*** is close indeed but has several meanings in both French and English so can be ambiguous depending on the context.

French ***prestation*** is related to the action (we kind of lend something) while ***service*** is the result of that action. We can say ***prestation de service***, ***service rendu*** or ***service fourni*** in French which might translate to ***provided service*** or ***service delivery*** depending on the context.

These definitions match what we call ***prestations***:

> **Service** ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/service))
>
> [...]
>
> 3 COUNTABLE NOUN **B1+**
> If an organization or company provides a particular service, they can do a particular job or a type of work for you.
> *The kitchen maintains a twenty-four-hour service and can be contacted via Reception.*
> *The larger firm was capable of providing a better range of services.*
>
> [...]
>
> 7 PLURAL NOUN [with poss]
> Your services are the things that you do or the skills that you use in your job, which other people find useful and are usually willing to pay you for.
> *I have obtained the services of a top photographer to take our pictures. [+ of]*
> *The performers have all offered their services free of charge.*

In both of your sentences, ***services provided by**[...]* should work.

Answer (score -1):

You might reasonably use *function*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/function)
> Function: the natural purpose (of something) or the duty (of a person)
>
> Function: to perform the purpose of a particular thing, or to perform the duties of a particular person

Even if the duty of the department is to produce something such as a document, or to search for it, or other material operations, they may be considered to be performing their function by delivering it or by their operations.

Comment: Would  the downvoter care to explain their depressed view of a reasoned answer? It is just possible that we may benefit from their presently unexpressed viewpoint.

Comment: I have translated for 36 years and prestations has never meant function.